# R logging; does it happen automatically?

Tags: r, logging

I usually save in a txt file all pertenent R commands I need to reproduce figures. My computer crashed in the middle of a project and the commands did not get saved.

Does R save commands issued in a session somewhere? Kind of like bash history?

Adrian

Comment: No. Not if it crashed.

Comment: Look for `.Rhistory` in your home directory (regardless of platform). If anything is recoverable, it will be in there. Depending on the specifics of the crash, @MrFlick is correct in that it's unlikely you'll get what you need back.

Comment: My home computer crashed, not my remote server where I was executing the R commands. So: @NCS ~ $ head ~/.Rhistory
head: cannot open `/home/adrian/.Rhistory' for reading: No such file or directory
Odd... I have CentOS